# Missing Sajdah during Jummah salaat behind Imaam

Tags: salat, hanafi, sajda

if during jummah salaat behind imaam, I joined salaat from beginning & during sajadah I did not hear call for 2nd sajdah as mike went silent & I stood along with others in congregation after only one sajdah, & completed remaining salaat with Imaam. Is my salaat valid?

Comment: Two sajoods are obligatory per rakat so leaving a sajood doesn't not complete the obligation, so the prayer is incomplete hence invalid. For more information regarding and related to this topic see : [What Are the Pillars, Obligatory Parts and Sunnah Acts of Prayer?](https://www.google.com/amp/s/islamqa.info/amp/en/answers/65847)

Comment: [Faraidh, Wajibat & other rulings of Salah](https://islamqa.org/hanafi/daruliftaa-birmingham/136138/faraidh-wajibat-other-rulings-of-salah/) answered according to hanafi fiqh.

Comment: Jazakallah khair

Answer (score 2):

The two sajood are one of the six obligatory/fard acts per rakat so leaving any obligatory act doesn't complete the rakat hence the salat/prayer is incomplete.

### Six obligated acts of Prayer

1. al-Tahrīmah (saying the first Allāhu Akbar)
2. Qiyām (standing).
3. Qirā’ah (reciting the Qur’ān, even if it be anāyah)
4. Rukūʿ
5. **Sujūd**
6. Final sitting of al-tashahud

### Ruling on solidarity prayer

> If any fard is omitted of the prayer then provided that one has not spoken or left one’s place of prayer then it is possible for one to still make up what one has missed.  **The general principle is that one makes up what one missed along with whatever else comes after it in a rakat.  So for example, if one missed a prostration then one merely prostrates followed by the tashahhud and salams.  If one missed a bowing (ruku) then one bows followed by two sajdas, the tashahhud and salams.  If one missed a whole rakat then one makes up a whole rakat.*[al-Bahr al-Ra’iq, 1:316, Dar al-Kutub al-Islami]***

If you did not meet the two conditions then you should pray again.

### Ruling on Congregational prayer

If you inattentively missed any of the obligatory acts of prayer behind the imam, *then you should redo what you left in the rakat after the imam does the first Salam (right_side).*

> So for example, if one missed a prostration then one merely prostrates followed by the tashahhud and salams.  If one missed a bowing (ruku) then one bows followed by two sajdas, the tashahhud and salams.  If one missed a whole rakat then one makes up a whole rakat. **[al-Bahr al-Ra’iq, 1:316, Dar al-Kutub al-Islami]**

If you did not make up the rakat after the imam finishes then should pray 4 rakat qada fard of zuhr instead of 2 rakat fard of Jumauh as there is no qada of Jumuah.

---

For more about this topic see :

- [Faraidh, Wajibat & other rulings of Salah](https://islamqa.org/hanafi/daruliftaa-birmingham/136138/faraidh-wajibat-other-rulings-of-salah/) by islamqa/hanafi
- [Leaving a necessary action in prayer](https://islamqa.org/hanafi/qibla-hanafi/42907/leaving-a-necessary-action-in-prayer-3/) by islamqa/hanafi
- [Prayer: missing a rakat…](https://islamqa.org/hanafi/qibla-hanafi/37010/prayer-missing-a-rakat/) by Islamqa/hanafi